# button function is not defined with htmlstring

Tags: javascript

I am able to display out all the details including the button. However, the main problem is that the when I click the button, nothing happens. It says that BtnRemoveAdmin() is not defined when I inspect for errors. However, I have function BtnRemoveAdmin()?? I have tried to move the function to htmlstring. Nothing works. I am not sure what went wrong.

```
(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
showadmin();
});

function showadmin() {
var url = serverURL() + "/showadmin.php";

var userid = "userid";
var employeename = "employeename";
var role ="role";

var JSONObject = {
    "userid": userid,
    "employeename": employeename,
    "role": role,
 };

$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'GET',
data: JSONObject,
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (arr) {
    _getAdminResult(arr);
},
    error: function () {
            alert("fail");
    }
});

}

function _getAdminResult(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    htmlstring = '<div class="grid-container">' +
                 '<div>' + arr[i].userid + '</div>' +
                 '<div>' + arr[i].employeename + '</div>' +
                 '<div>' + arr[i].role + '</div>' +
                 '<div>' + '<button onclick="BtnRemoveAdmin()">Remove</button>' + // 'BtnRemoveAdmin' is not defined
                 '</div>' ;
    $("#name").append(htmlstring);
}   

function BtnRemoveAdmin() {
    var data = event.data;
    removeadmin(data.id);
    } 
}


function removeadmin(userid) {
 window.location = "removeadmin.php?userid=" + userid;
}


})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code is defined inside an IIFE.

That includes `BtnRemoveAdmin`.

When you generate your JavaScript as a string, it is evaled in a different scope.

`BtnRemoveAdmin` does not exist in that scope.

---

Don't generate your HTML by mashing strings together.

Use DOM instead.

```
function _getAdminResult(arr) {
    var gridcontainers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var gridcontainer = $("<div />").addClass("grid-container");
        gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].userid));
        gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].employeename));
        gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].role));
        gridcontainer.append($("<div />").append(
            $("<button />")
                .on("click", BtnRemoveAdmin)
                .text("Remove")
        ));
        gridcontainers.push(gridcontainer);
        }
    $("#name").append(gridcontainers);
}
```

Comment: Hey, it is now working. Unfortunately I'm having "Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference" error for my function BtnRemoveAdmin() Thought that it was due to me not putting event inside the paratheses but still getting the same error....

Comment: Using `function BtnRemoveAdmin()` instead of `function BtnRemoveAdmin(event)` means that `event` is the non-standard global event object which doesn't have good browser support instead of the standard event object which does. So always use `function BtnRemoveAdmin(event)`

Comment: Unrelated to that, `data` is not a property I would expect to see on an event object. I've no idea what you expect `event.data.id` to be.

Comment: Oh, now I get it... Everything is working perfectly fine now. Thank you for the help and explanation!

Answer (score -1):

I use JQuery, and sometimes I get the same problem with plain JS functions not being called.

So I create JQuery functions :

```
$.fn.extend({
    btnRemoveAdmin: function() {
        ...//Do what you want here
    }
});
```

To call it use :

```
<button onclick="$().btnRemoveAdmin();"></button>
```

Hope it helps you !

Comment: This is effectively the same as making a global, except it puts code which has nothing to do with jQuery inside jQuery. That's going to be really horrible to maintain.